# What are the ways to avoid VPN/Proxy detection in a site that probably uses a database like scamanalytics to check for proxies?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

I'm trying to get in a site geo-blocked due to sanctions in Venezuela but it also blocks VPN/Proxies. After some exploration of how the site works I'm thinking its proxy detection is based in checking on an API like scamanalytics if the fraud score is high or if any of the flags "Anonymizing VPN", "TOR Exit node", "Proxy", etc are on. (Example in the image below) [image]

The reason why I think this is because some people have reported that it blocks them from joining the site due to "VPN" usage when no VPN is being used, a high fraud score in scamanalytics could be the reason of the false VPN detection.

Now that I probably know how the site detects proxy usage. What are the ways you'd suggest me to avoid being detected? Free or not.

Comment: This is offtopic here. https://superuser.com/help/on-topic Which site?

Comment: Dont use a proxy with a known IP address or one that adds typical proxy headers.  Finding such a beast may not be easy.  I might look for a supplier that offers a "low end box" VM that does not host with a big cloud provider and run my owm VPN on it.

Comment: @Gantendo If this is offtopic where should I ask? Sorry I am new

Comment: @pinkWojak The Stack Exchange network is so fucking huge and confusing basically no one knows what belongs where and why. I know next to nothing. Maybe our brothers and sisters over at security.stackexchange.com are more knowledgeable on the topic of proxies than we are.

Comment: If the detection is by IP address, some VPNs offer dedicated or static IP addresses that aren’t shared with other VPN users.

Answer (score 1):

Residential proxy is one way to bypass VPN server detection in Scamalytics, which is using [IP2Proxy](https://www.ip2location.com/database/ip2proxy) VPN detection service.